# C# Lambda WhereIf or statement

Tags: c#, search, parameters, lambda

I have many unknown search parameters to evaluate.   At most I would only have 5 search levels currently just showing 3 levels. 
I have been trying to use the WhereIf extension but perhaps thats not not the best way.  I would prefer a solution in a lambda or linq statement.   Here is a mock up:

[image]

Consider:

```
Animal_ID    Breed     Color    Age   Weight
1            Poodle    White      3     10
2            Shepard   Brown      4     15
3            Afghan    Brown      9     40
4            Terrier   White      7     25
5            Maltese   White      12    14
```

Forgive me, I realize this is incomplete.  I started doing this but then realized this is going to get complex.

```
List<Animal> animals = db.Animals
  //I know I can do this.   
  //.WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty("Search"), x => (x.Color == "white") || (x.Breed == "terrier"))             
  //I want "OR" here
  .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty("Search_1_IsSomething"), x => (x.Color == "white")) // OR
  .WhereIf(!String.IsNullOrEmpty("Search_2_OR_IsSomething"), x => (x.Breed == "terrier"))
  .ToList();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This expression will always evaluate to `true`: `!String.IsNullOrEmpty("Search_1_IsSomething")`. What is the point of it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with String.IsNullOrEmpty("Search_1_IsSomething") because the result will always be the same see the answer of Stephan it would be a much better approach unless String.IsNullOrEmpty("Search_1_IsSomething") will have a parameter like String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText).
ALSO from your code it will first get all the animals that are white and then from that result it will get all the breeds that are terrier, you would be better off with WhereIf(condition, x => (x.Color == "white") ||  (x.Breed == "terrier"))

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish the same thing without WhereIf at all.

```
var result = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVar) ? 
    animals.Where(x => x.Color == "white" || 
    x.Breed == "terrier") : new List<Animal>();
```

You would probably just want it to search for the passed in search term though.

```
var result = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVar) ? 
        animals.Where(x => x.Color == searchVar || 
        x.Breed == searchVar) : new List<Animal>(); //or return full list (animals) if search term is null
```

Edit: Ran a test in linqpad and it seems to run fine.

```
void Main()
{
    SearchAnimals("white").Dump();
}

public List<Animal> SearchAnimals(string searchVar)
{
    var animals = new List<Animal>()
    {
        new Animal { Animal_ID = 1, Color = "black", Breed = "other" },
        new Animal { Animal_ID = 2, Color = "white", Breed = "other" },
        new Animal { Animal_ID = 3, Color = "blue", Breed = "terrier" },
        new Animal { Animal_ID = 4, Color = "green", Breed = "other" }
    };

    var result = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVar) ? 
        animals.Where(x => x.Color == "white" || 
        x.Breed == "terrier") : new List<Animal>();

    return result.ToList();
}

public class Animal
{
    public int Animal_ID { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
}
```

Returns:

```
List<Animal> (2 items)

Animal_ID   Color    Breed
2           white    other 
3           blue     terrier
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen I like where you are headed with this answer but it didn't compile.  I even changed List to IQueryable.

Comment: I ran a test in linqpad and it seems to run ok, and return the items you are looking for. "searchVar" in this case isn't being used, that would just need to be switched out for the second part of my answer that is searching based off the search term passed in. Truthfully you want it to be one or the other not both so saying breed "or" color is equal to passed in search term will give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking about is how to use a second extension method to specify "or". With Linq, this is not possible, and it's by the nature of how Linq works.

Once you call `Where/WhereIf` or any similar method, the enumerable is filtered down to matching objects. Calling additional filtering methods on the result enumerable won't add objects back: it can only remove more objects.